# SQLite: How to set default input type to `text` instead of `textarea`

Tags: sqlite, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, formhelper

I am using sqlite in my Cake project, where `VarChar` data type is not exists, and the inputs comes as `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="name" required="required" id="name" rows="5">Value</textarea>
```

I wonder if there is a way to make the default type setted to `text` and not `textarea`.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does have/recognize a `VARCHAR` *data type* too, it's just being resolved internally to the generic *storage type* `TEXT`.

So while it doesn't make a difference to SQLite whether you are using `CHARACTER`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc, it will make a difference for CakePHP when it inspects the schema.

So, long story short, use `VARCHAR` and you're set (don't forget to clear the model cache (`tmp/cache/model`) after making changes to the schema).

See also **https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html**